# when using pymysql , i cannot connect to server "error 1045 : Access Denied for user". What should I do?

Tags: mysql, ssl, pymysql

I'm using Python.
I can connect my localhost in MySQL. There's no problem

but there are another external server and Problem is I cannot connect that server with error code (1045, "Access denied for user 'drug_team'@'172.30.1.254' (using password: YES)")

```
import pymysql
host = "server_host_name"
port = port_number
user = "server_user_name"
pw = "server_password"
db = "server_database"
conn = pymysql.connect(host = host, port = port, user = user, passwd = pw, db = db)
conn
```

I thought It's because of SSL issue.
but i dont know where SSL is.
How can I get to know about my SSL location.

(I can connect with MySQL workbench program)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ssl, because your client established a valid connection to the server. But that username@host and password combination you provided was not accepted.

Comment: I really Thank you for you explanation. If it has nothing to do with SSL, What is most possible factor about this problem?   c.f.) arguments(host,port,user,pw,db) is correct.

Comment: For MySQL access the username consists of two parts: the username itself and the host from where the connection is established. Check your privileges table if you have allowed `drug_team@172.30.1.254`. obviously one of these parameters is not correct